# Sqlite cannot exit after entering ls

Tags: sqlite, shell, ubuntu, ls

I installed SQLite on an Ubuntu Server, started it up and entered ls. Now I'm stuck in ...> as you can see below

```
sqlite> ls
    ...>ls
    ...>^C
    ...>exit
    ...>quit
```

and so on. I cannot exit from the ...> what can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will exit program.

---

To end statement just type `;` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
sqlite> ls
   ...> a
   ...> 
   ...> 
   ...> ads
   ...> ;
SQL error: near "ls": syntax error
```